# Husky add command is deprecated?

Tags: node.js, git, githooks, husky

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://dev.to/mahmudulhsn/install-husky-in-your-project-for-proper-commit-lint-with-pre-commit-hooks-25b2) on how to add a commit msg hook with Husky.

And this is the command given in the tutorial:

```
npx husky add .husky/commit-msg 'npx commitlint --edit $1'
```

However when ran it errors with this message:

```
add command is deprecated
```

What should we be using instead of `add`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This tutorial](https://medium.com/@abpeter14/how-to-install-commitlint-husky-2024-f1157f14006f) has updated instructions.

To install husky just do:

```
npx husky init
```

Then install the commit msg file like this:

```
echo "npx --no -- commitlint --edit \$1" > .husky/commit-msg
```

Comment: yes i guess it was depreciated from v7 onwards